# Route all traffic through IPSEC tunnel

Tags: linux, ipsec

I'm using Strongswan on CentOS as IPSEC VPN server. Is possible to tell client (win7) to route all traffic through tunnel interface after tunnel is up?

Here is my ipsec.conf

```
config setup

conn %default
    ikelifetime=60m
    keylife=20m
    rekeymargin=3m
    keyingtries=1
config setup

conn %default
    ikelifetime=60m
    keylife=20m
    rekeymargin=3m
    keyingtries=1
    keyexchange=ikev2
    ike=aes256-sha1-modp1024!
    esp=aes256-sha1!
    dpdaction=clear
    dpddelay=300s
    rekey=no

conn rw-eap
    left=%defaultroute
    leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
    leftsourceip=62.244.57.9
    leftid=@master.ln.ua
    leftcert=server.crt
    leftauth=pubkey
    leftfirewall=no
    right=%any
    rightauth=eap-mschapv2
    rightsourceip=62.244.57.9/29
    rightsendcert=never
    eap_identity=%any
    auto=add
```

Comment: Your config should achieve that (`leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0`). But please have a look at the strongSwan wiki for [details on forwarding and split-tunneling](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/ForwardingAndSplitTunneling).